# How to use RackPick to retrieve particular state of agent from Storage in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

In my model I have 10 products using Statechart.

[image]

I am defining color of each state like this

[image]

I am storing the products in racks along multiple racks using

[image]

Now, let's come to retrieval. The method I used randomly picks all types of product from Racks in chronological order using the following logic

```
if(A1_RackNo  == 1){
    if(Rack_A1.size() + Rack_A1.reserved() + rackStore_A1.queueSize() == 0 && rackPick.queueSize() == 0){
        A1_RackNo = 2;
        holdRack_2.unblock();
        traceln(A1_RackNo);}
```

Upto this everything runs smoothly. But I am failing to RackPick item Product for a particular state. Suppose I have a demand only for products in P1 State. Once order is placed, forklifts can go to the rack and retrieve only the P1 Products.